# How to increase max execution time for a script in node.js ?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am using node's async module to connect 50 mongodb databases fill them with data.

I use async.eachSeries for this in my express application.

However the execution always doesn't seems to go beyond 120s.

I have encountered a few links saying app.timeout = x , where x is the number of milliseconds we desire our script to execute.however this doesn't works for me.

Comment: What mongodb solution are you using? It is probably the mongodb client, not node.js. As far as I know, node.js scripts usually do not have a timeout associated with them.

Comment: @HyoByun is right. I have node scripts running all the time that just keep on plugging away. It's likely mongo. Node scripts can run forever unless you've specifically built them not to.

Comment: @HyoByun , I am using npm mongodb ^1.4.7

Comment: @RohitNayal did you find any working solution ?

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way i guess and this works for me.

```
var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  server.timeout = 2000000;
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer for node/express appliaciton on router specific functions

```
res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
res.connection.setTimeout(0); // this will prevent the timeout
```

above line of code prevents request timeout.

Thanks